# Table Incompatifilities BusinessObjects

Tags: business-objects

I am aware that is is a must to define Aggregate Navigation when dealing with Aggregate Awareness.
The question is: Are table incmpatibilities in Aggregate Navigation automatically created when  Contexts are defined?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can click the "Detect Incompatibility" button in the Aggregate Navigation dialog to automatically detect incompatibilities.